# Hardwiring input in DFAs and PDAs

Tags: finite-automata, pushdown-automata, computation-models

A Turing Machine can be converted into a Turing Machine that has a specific input coded into it's description. This Turing Machine can then be run on empty input. Can we do the same for PDAs or DFAs?

I am familiar with models of computation such as Conway's Game of Life where the rules are fixed and the entire computation solely depends on the initial state. It is also easy to imagine this in a Turing Machine where **the input is encoded on the tape.**

I would imagine it might be possible for a model like Push-Down Automata where the input is encoded in the stack, but I am unaware if there is a formal construction of this sort. How would one do this for a DFA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can easily build a PDA or DFA that immediately halts and rejects (regardless of its input); and you can easily build one that immediately halts and accepts (regardless of its input).  Those are the only two cases you need, so the answer to your question is yes.